# Passing custom variable from conky to lua

Tags: conky

I am trying to use [this rings script](https://github.com/tuxtor/conky-lua-rings-gentoo/blob/master/clock_rings.lua) to make nice rings appear on my desktop. It allows for customization, addition of more rings, or so it says. How do I feed the output of my python script to these rings?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but have you considered having your Python write both the `lua` and `conky` scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm not sure whether questions this old need to be answered but since it's returned in search results, it may as well have an answer.*

The lua script declares functions that accept parameters, E.G. 
`function draw_ring(cr,t,pt)`.  The solution is to declare a function that receives your python script values.

```
function myCustomUI(neededValue)
```

In your conkyrc, you call that function, passing the python script's output.  Something like this:

```
${lua myCustomUI ${<python call here>}}
```

Your next question is how to get your output into that variable?
Here you go:

```
${execi 3600 python script.py}
```

This makes your conkyrc code look like:

```
${lua myCustomUI ${execi 3600 python script.py}}
```

Of course, if your script is executable then you could drop the `python` from the execi call.  The 3600 is just a repetition delay to avoid running the script constantly.  More information can be found [here](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html)

Additionally, conky variables are available within the lua environment so you can make the `execi` call from there if you want, using the same format.

Answer (score 0):

provide them on the commandline or as environment vars

Comment: With this little detail I don't think the original poster will be helped.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Perhaps you could elaborate this a bit more?